# Syntax error in a SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

I want to create/update a table (stuff) whenever data in another table (otherStuff) is changed. I keep getting a syntax error in my code at my select statmement. I know very basics of SQL and i don't understand what i have done wrong

```
create trigger TestTrigger
on dbo.otherStuff
after insert , update , delete
as
begin
    drop table dbo.stuff
    create table dbo.stuff as
```

> this is the select where the error occurs

```
    SELECT ID, Name
```

> this is the select where the error occurs

```
    from dbo.otherStuff
end;
go
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?, I mean, how could we know what the problem is?

Comment: There's no such thing as "CREATE TABLE ... AS" in SQL Server. Where did you find this syntax? It is valid in other platforms but you can't transpose things from one database platform to another without expecting some kind of conversion.

Comment: Yeah, there are definitely different flavors of SQL. SQL Server uses Transact-SQL, and different versions of SQL Server even have variations, never mind across completely different products by completely different vendors, all implementing their own subset of the ANSI standard and their own proprietary extensions. Stop using tutorial sites like that, they're generally quite terrible. Start with [official product documentation from your vendor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the extra information. This should help me avoid mistakes like this in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support the `CREATE TABLE AS` syntax.  You can use `SELECT * INTO` like:

```
SELECT ID, Name
INTO dbo.stuff
FROM dbo.otherStuff
```

Comment: @Lamak I think the OP is trying explicitly `CREATE TABLE ... AS` which works a lot like `SELECT INTO` in other platforms but not SQL Server. SQL Server expects `CREATE TABLE ... () WITH ()...`

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yeah, that's likely. At first op didn't even added the `after insert , update , delete` part of the trigger so I thought s/he had just added some code without really looking

Comment: Thank you for the help. Its hard to distinguish between different versions of SQL

Comment: @Tom Where do you get that my comment contradicts your answer? I was merely clarifying for Lamak, who sounded like he didn't notice the `AS` part.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, gotcha, sorry. Thought you were saying the only way would be to do a full `CREATE TABLE ...() WITH ()...`

Comment: @Lamak I did forget to write `after insert , update , delete` at first. it was a mistake on my part when copying from _cmd Line_